# JavaScript game ending alert?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a functioning maze with arrow movement and coins to collect, however I'm breaking the game when trying to display a message that comes up once the user has collected all 6 rewards.

I have tried to copy someone's alert from github and apply it as best as I think I can to my work but it just breaks the canvas and nothing actually appears in the browser.

My code is below:

```js
character = {
  x: 6,
  y: 4
}

var el = document.getElementById('game');

function drawWorld() {
  el.innerHTML = '';
  for (var y = 0; y < map.length; y = y + 1) {
    for (var x = 0; x < map[y].length; x = x + 1) {
      if (map[y][x] === 1) {
        el.innerHTML += "<div class='borders'></div>";
      } else if (map[y][x] === 2) {
        el.innerHTML += "<div class='reward'></div>";
      } else if (map[y][x] === 3) {
        el.innerHTML += "<div class='ground'></div>";
      } else if (map[y][x] === 5) {
        el.innerHTML += "<div class='character'></div>";
      }
    }
    el.innerHTML += "<br>";
  }

  winGame();
}

function winGame() {
  if (!map[5].includes(2))
    alert("Well done!");
}


drawWorld();

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    if (map[character.y][character.x - 1] !== 1) {
      map[character.y][character.x] = 3;
      character.x = character.x - 1;
      map[character.y][character.x] = 5;
      drawWorld();
    }
  } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
    if (map[character.y - 1][character.x] !== 1) {
      map[character.y][character.x] = 3;
      character.y = character.y - 1;
      map[character.y][character.x] = 5;
      drawWorld();
    }
  } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
    if (map[character.y][character.x + 1] !== 1) {
      map[character.y][character.x] = 3;
      character.x = character.x + 1;
      map[character.y][character.x] = 5;
      drawWorld();
    }
  } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
    if (map[character.y + 1][character.x] !== 1) {
      map[character.y][character.x] = 3;
      character.y = character.y + 1;
      map[character.y][character.x] = 5;
      drawWorld();
    }
  }

  console.log(map)

}
```

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `winGame();
}`
This is a `}` here but I couldn't see the opening `{`. Have you pasted the relevant code in it's entirety?

Comment: hey, you don't have the `map` variable defined anywhere in your code, but you're referring to it a lot. Are you sure this is all the code that you have?

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram That's the closing tag for the beginning one in the drawWorld() function, I thought I had to pass the winGame() through here.

Comment: @GlebKost My map is defined with a 15x15 canvas but it wouldn't let me post this if I included it - I should of mentioned this, sorry.

Comment: For fun, let's try

`window.setTimeout(function(){winGame();}, 500)`;

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram Where shall I put this in? Sorry if it's obvious, very new to JavaScript

Comment: Replace `winGame();` with `window.setTimeout(function(){winGame();}, 500)`;

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram I've included this, it now comes up with the alert whenever I land on this one specific point on the canvas as supposed to after I've collected all the rewards. So it is working but it will come up if I go straight to that point and still have all the other rewards left

Comment: That will be because of the logic `if (!map[5].includes(2))`.

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram I'm struggling writing the statement that basically tells the alert to come up when all of the rewards have been collected. I thought off the research I did that this logic would work but it's done something, just not what I wanted.

Comment: @JackC98 : That deviates from what you asked above. Your question was 'using an alert breaks the canvas' but what you are asking now is help with the logic. You should probably edit your question or ask a new one. Good luck!

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram I said in the question description "..however I'm breaking the game when trying to display a message that comes up once the user has collected all 6 rewards."? Is this not correctly asked?

Comment: You also said "I have tried to copy someone's alert from github and apply it as best as I think I can to my work but it just breaks the canvas and nothing actually appears in the browser."

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram Okay apologies I will edit that section now. I don't suppose you can help do you while you're here haha?